# Javascript create element and add HTML

Tags: javascript, html

say for instance i have the following line:

```
        var arrowBase = document.createElement('div')
```

Now within this div tag i want to add some HTML (i.e text).

Then i tried the following:

```
arrowBase.innerHTML('hello');
```

However this does nothing:S

i have also tried: `arrowBase.HTML('hello');`

But once again without any result

I know is that rather simple but in my search i could'nt find the answer hope someone is able to help me out here

Comment: Make sure you insert/append the element to the page.

Comment: @Jeffman, there is no need to append it first

Comment: When OP said it didn't work, I assumed he saw no evidence. Not appending it could be a reason.

Comment: @Jeffman, or the reason is invalid code. ;)

Comment: Sounds like you'll swim easier with jQuery: `$("#arrowBase").html("hello");`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Read the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.innerHTML), it is not a method.

```
arrowBase.innerHTML = 'hello';
```

Answer (score 0):

> arrowBase.textContent = "HELLO"

also does the same thing but only text can be specified. Whereas in `innerHTML` html tags can be specified along with the text.